# mobx state tree: if wrong type, discard value and use default instead of throwing an error

Tags: javascript, mobx-state-tree

In mobx state tree, if the type is wrong, it throws an error. Is there a way to make it not throw an error, and just discard the value and use a default? (`types.optional` works for a predefined set, but not any value of the wrong type.)

Setup

```
const TestModel = types.model({
  testProp: "",
})

const testModel = TestModel.create({
  testProp: 5 // or null, [], 9, undefined, etc
})
```

Desired

```
console.log(testModel.testProp) // ""
```

Actual

```
// Error thrown.
```

Basically I want to guarantee the type of inconsistent server data so I don't have to `?.` everywhere.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in MST yet. Also there is no typechecks in production at all unless you explicitly using `typecheck` function by yourself. https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/API/#typecheck

Comment: Are you trying to do something like const TestModel = types.model({
  testProp: types.optional(types.string, ""),
}) ?